# Make last td as row

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/wYA9K/55/

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th colspan="1" style="width: 10%">TH1</th>
    <th colspan="1" style="width: 60%">TH2</th>
    <th colspan="1" style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>  <-- what should i do??
</thead>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 10%">a</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 60%">b</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 30%">c</td>
    <td>UNDERNEATH SPANNING WHOLE ROW</td> <-- what should i do??
</tr>
```

I am trying to make the last td to expand the whole row.
Is there anyway possible to do this?

Comment: Make it a new `<tr>` and use `colspan="3"` in the `<td>`

Comment: You're missing `<tr>` in the header.

Comment: Like Barmar said: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wYA9K/56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last column of each row to appear, and you're willing to include explicit styles on all of the other columns, you can float them:

```css
td, th {
  display: block;
  float: left;

  /* for visibility only */
  border: 1px solid grey;

  /* so we don't run out of space with 100% total width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td:last-child, th:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" style="width: 10%">TH1</th>
      <th colspan="1" style="width: 60%">TH2</th>
      <th colspan="1" style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 10%">a</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 60%">b</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 30%">c</td>
    <td>UNDERNEATH SPANNING WHOLE ROW</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 10%">a</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 60%">b</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="width: 30%">c</td>
    <td>UNDERNEATH SPANNING WHOLE ROW</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new row with `colspan="3"`. Also, `colspan="1"` is the default so you don't need to clutter the markup with it.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">TH1</th>
            <th style="width: 60%">TH2</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%">a</td>
            <td style="width: 60%">b</td>
            <td style="width: 30%">c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">UNDERNEATH SPANNING WHOLE ROW</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Problem is each tr adds a border.  And I want to have the last td inside same tr.  You guys rock!